# Why doesn't this Python regexp with Percent sign work?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This is a very simple regex that should match but I can't understand why it doesn't.

**Here it is:** a word boundary **+** a percent sign (non-capturing) **+** a word boundary:

```py
import re

re.sub(r'(\b)(?:%)(\b)',r'\1tok_pctg\2',"foo bar %")
# should return "foo bar tok_pctg" but returns "foo bar %" instead!
```

**P.S.:** Running Python v 3.6.9

Comment: Word breaks (`\b`) only match between a word character (`[A-Za-z_]`) and a non-word character. `%` is not next to a word character so the word breaks don't match. You could try `re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(?:%)(?!\S)',r'tok_pctg',r"foo bar %")`

Comment: I'll try that. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: Yes it does @Nick